# Removing confirmation box for moving message from junk to inbox

Tags: outlook.com

When trying to move a message from junk mail to inbox on outlook.com, there recently began appearing a pop-up dialogue asking if I want to mark the sender as safe.

Is there any way to prevent this pop-up from appearing?

I tried searching the settings as well as duckduckgoing it (it's a bit more of a mouthful than googling, isn't it?), but couldn't find anything regarding this dialogue box.

[image: Image of the pop-up]

Comment: Please translate the pop-up content (better if you post a image on English, on several web apps this might be done by temporarily change the account language).

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a solution to this irritation for several months, and this is the first result I have come across that actually addresses this problem.  Unfortunately, neither of us has a solution.  It's almost aggravating enough to start using Thunderbird instead of their webmail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).